# SCNView snapshot image does not include the overlaySKScene

Tags: ios, scenekit

Using **iOS 10.3** & **Xcode 8.3**

I add an overlay scene like this:

```
     self.scnView.overlaySKScene = someUI;  //SpriteKit SKScene
```

But when I try to take a snapshot:

```
     UIImage *image = [self.scnView snapshot];
```

The snapshot image shows only the 3D scene but not the overlay scene. But it all looks ok on-screen, meaning I can see the 3D scene and the overlay.

How do I get a snapshot that includes the overlayScene?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Oops*.  snapshot works fine and shows the overlay too if you set the scnView.background to any color (with alpha=1), except clearColor.

I had set the the scnView.backgroundColor to clearColor.

```
    self.scnView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```

I assumed the overlay to be on top of/above the 3D Scene and background to be below/behind the 3D scene. So I didn't expect the clearColor background to apply to the overlay scene as well.  Oh well.

Comment: I have to wait at least 9 hrs before I can mark it as correct.